# How to calculate cross-validation score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am quite new to the scikit-learn module and therefore reading the tutorials carefully here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html. But, I got stuck while playing with my data. I want to try the cross validation score (CVS) scheme with my data. Can someone please help me out?

I have a data file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8xq7qm5gy7lnjw/data.dat?dl=0

The 'x' and 'y' columns represent the actual and model values resp. I just want to know how good my model values are and therefore want to calculate CVS. Can someone guide me with a code how can I do that? Since I am starting so might be short of information, please let me know if there is need of any other information.

I started like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

data = np.loadtxt("deviation.dat")
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=3)
for train, test in k_fold.split(data):
 print('Train: %s | test: %s' % (train, test))
```

This prints:

```
Train: [25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74] | test: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
Train: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74] | test: [25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
Train: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49] | test: [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74]
```

But now I want to know what is the score?

N.B.: 'deviation.dat' is just the (abs(column x - column y )) of the data file.

Comment: can you share what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck? Also, there are a lot of resources out there that can guide you Ex: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6
http://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/data-science/data-science-cross-validating-in-python/
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/improve-model-performance-cross-validation-in-python-r/

Comment: Unfortunately, I got stuck in the beginning itself (please have a look at the main post, edited now).

Comment: are you getting any errors in the code you added? Where exactly are you stuck? Sorry for asking again, but you really have to be specific if you expect help on this forum.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, in the meantime, I updated again my post. There is no error but I simply just want to know what is the CV score in the 'K-fold' case mentioned in my post? There should be a value, right? or am I asking something horribly wrong? please let me know

Comment: how well do you understand the concept of Cross validation? I am asking this because it seems you are short on the concepts of cross validation. Are you basically looking for someone to explain cv to you?

Comment: I am just starting the cross validation concept. In the very first example here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html, they calculated the CVS which I understood. So, I also thought in the 'k-fold' method we can also calculate the CVS which will give me a value.

Comment: if you look at the second code block, you will see that they have fitted a model using 'clf = ...' and then calculated its score. Cross validation is performed to check if we are over fitting our model so obviously you need to select a model that will train on the train data and perform predictions on the hold out dataset and a final score will be calculated. Head over to section 3.1.1 to see this in action. Also, are you mew to machine learning?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Yes, I am new to machine learning. I am in fact not into machine-learning. I just wanted to simply test my model with a cross-validation scheme and to have an idea how good my model is in predicting.

Comment: that nice. Let me know if I can be of help further

Comment: Thank you again, I think I have to read more as I still don't understand it fully.